# Setting value of <input/> in Angular 2 via observable

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs5

I am trying to use `@ngrx/store` to keep track of the values in a form. One of the inputs can only have digits. When I enter data, the Redux state is correctly storing only digits, but the updated value is not being reflected in the input field, it still shows the un-sanitized value.

EDITED: This problem isn't specific to ngrx/store. Populating the value of the input field from any observable causes this issue. Tried storing the data in a Behavior Subject from an @Injectable class and exposing publicly `.asObservable()` but ran into the same issue.

e.g.)

Input value of "123abc"

Redux stores "123" (Correct)

Input field still shows "123abc" (Incorrect, doesn't match Redux state)

EDITED: If we use sample input of `123abc` and then type in the digit `4`, we visually see the input value update to `1234`, same as the Redux store.

```js
export class InputComponent {
  private value: Observable<string>;

  constructor(private store: Store<IAppState>) {
    this.value = store
      .map(appState => appState.form.value)
      .distinctUntilChanged();
  }

  public onChange(value: string): void {
    const sanitizedValue: string =
      value.replace(/\D/g, '');

    this.store.dispatch(updateValue(sanitizedValue));
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input
    autofocus
    type="tel"
    [ngModel]="(value | async)"
    id="form-value"
    (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)"
  />
  <label for="form-value">Form Value</label>
</div>
```